# Highlighting selected menu item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Page named index.php contains 1 menu with 3 options. Menu links lead to URL:index.php?id_product=xy. Then PHP reads id_product with GET and prints details from database. Now I want to highlight(change color of text) of the last clicked menu item. How to do this? Is it possible to read the value of id_product form URL with jQuery and then to add text effect to clicked menu item? Any ideas?

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='index.php?id_product=1'>1</a></li>
  <li><a href='index.php?id_product=2'>2</a></li>
  <li><a href='index.php?id_product=3'>3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is possible with just PHP and CSS

Comment: Yes, it is possible. How depends on your secret code.

Comment: Flag it as "active" and change the color accordingly.

Comment: There are many ways to do this - which way did you want to go?

Comment: using jquery/javascript and css if possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add some id tags to your elements:

```
<ul>
  <li><a id="1" href='index.php?id_product=1'>1</a></li>
  <li><a id="2" href='index.php?id_product=2'>2</a></li>
  <li><a id="3" href='index.php?id_product=3'>3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then add class "highlight" to the proper $_GET variable using javascript/jquery and a sprinkle of php:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var selected_product = "<?php echo $_GET['id_product']; ?>";
    if(selected_product !== "")
     $("#"+selected_product).addClass("highlight");
});
</script>
```

Finally create the highlight class with css:

```
<style>
    a.highlight { color: red; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$menu_items = array(1, 2, 3); 
$product_id = $_GET['id_product'];

echo "<ul>";
foreach($menu_items as $menu_item){
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?id_product=" . $menu_item . "'" . (isset($product_id) && $product_id == $menu_item ? " class='active'" : "") . ">" . $menu_item . "</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

This will add an active class to the menu item based on `id_product`

Comment: The isset() test is a bit superfluous; you set it 4 lines back.

Comment: Not necessarily, the menu could be displayed on a page that doesn't have the `id_product` var set.

Comment: Ah yes, setting to NULL will not have isset() return true.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work.

```
$(function()){
    var file_url = window.location.pathname.substring(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
    $("ul > li > a[href="+file_url+"]").addClass("selected");
}
```

another way should be

```
$(function(){
    $("ul > li > a[href$='"+window.location.search+"']").addClass("selected");
})
```

anyway it is easier only with php :)

```
foreach ($products as $p) {
  $selected = ($_GET["id_product"]==$p->id)?" class='selected'":"";
  echo "<a href='?id_product=".$p->id."'".$selected.">".$p->id."</a>";
}
```

or

```
<style>
    a[href*='id_product=<?=$_GET["id_product"]?>']{ color:red; }
</style>
```